# Make one of windows service process as user [exe4j]

Tags: java, windows-services, exe4j

While you are working with vncserver, you can *Install* it or *run*.
If you **Install** it, the service would be installed and after starting the service, two processes would be appear: one is system and the other is process.
If you **run** it, the you don't need to install the service and both process are user.

Now I've made a java program and make it service with exe4j.
After installing and starting my service, two process would be appear like the vnc but both are **system**.
Is there any way to run one another on user?
Should I Change my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows services run under a system account by default. With the /install command line parameter, there is no way to specify a different user (unlike with install4j where the "Install a service" action allows you to specify a different user).

With exe4j, you would have to change the user manually in the service properties dialog.